# session variables losing value in deployed application

Tags: asp.net

When application is deployed on server and accessed from the client, the session variables are blank

`If IsNothing(Session("Order")) Then`   is always returning true.

The session variables have values when tested on the development machine.

This is the entry in web.config

`<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="true" timeout="60" />`

Comment: If you log out then log back in and hit the page / process that should set Session("Order") does it then work?

Comment: There is no login for the application. It is an intranet application and uses the System login

Comment: Why are you using cookieless sessions?  Are you passing the session id along correctly in the urls?  If not, your session will be lost.

Comment: Not sure why coookieless in used. This application was initially developed in VS 2003. I converted to VS 2010 (dotnet 4.0 and IIS 7.5) I faced many issues and fixed all of them. This seems to be the last one that I need to fix. The URL looks like this `http://intranet1_tsdb/TOrders/techs/orders/edit/tmaker.aspx?tid=EP9996&oid=59131&fmtid=TMAKER`

Comment: there is no session id.  turn cookies on

Comment: `http://intranet1_tsdb/TOrders/(S(mwwtvsfr2ysy2thycli1h0y1))/techs/orders/edit/tmaker.aspx?tid=EP9996&oid=59131&fmtid=TMAKER` This is what I am getting now. But a new session value is generated each time. In Global.ascx,in the Session_Start, I initialized it using `Session("Order") = oOrder. But still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

When are you setting the session?  Also, is this hosted?  Some 3rd party hosts recycle worker processes/application pools constantly and it kills your session.  Make sure you have your own application pool as well.  Also, cookieless could be a problem for you.

Comment: The application uses the default application pool